# Have Angular get bool from controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a project in angular that I need to have it talk to a rest api controller I am using. The main goal of it is to just give a bool if the username and pass is valid or not. The controller works with some test data so thats not the problem. My problem comes from having to use angular to communicate with it.

So far my attempts have included

```
                var data = new FormData();
                    data.append("User" , User);
                    data.append("Pass", Pass);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: $scope.itTransport.url($scope, 'login'),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (results) {
                        alert(results); 
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    }
            });
```

I have this part working on a post and thought it may have worked simiraly but no luck.

```
$scope.http({ method: 'GET', url: $scope.itTransport.url($scope, 'login', User, Pass )});
```

Like the other one I have similar code working on a post that works but no luck with this.

Comment: Code looks strange. Please consider to read documentation of http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: From what I understand from that documentation when I read it prior was that the second attempt fit that with me declaring the method type and url.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple:

```
$http.get($scope.itTransport.url($scope, 'login'), {params:data})
.success(function(results){
    alert(results);
})
.error(function(response, status, headers) {
     alert(response);
});
```

where data is some object (for example, data = {username:'user',password:'pwd'})

Answer (score 0):

Do not prefix $http with $scope. $http is a service which should be injected.

See the example at the bottom of the docs:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

```
function FetchCtrl($scope, $http) {
    ...
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/data/'})
    .success(function(data, status) { ... })
    .error(function(data, status) { ... });
    ...
}
```